# How to create instance while installing SQL server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, installation

I have installed  VS 2012 Professional, and later SQL Server 2008 SP1. After that I am trying to install `SQLManagementStudio_x64_Enu`. But I did get the option to set instance name [Database Engine Service]. Properly I have to the set option like in the image. But I have options like :

```
Instance Feature

Shared features

   1. Management Tools-Basic

   2. SQL Client Connectivity SDK

Redistributable Feature
```

If I select all checkboxes under `Shared Feature`, SQL Server installed successfully.

But while opening SQL Server Management Studio in server name list is empty.

[image: Instance Name]

Comment: Like in the image.I did not get option Database engine service. Let me know how can i get that....

Comment: When you installed SQL Server 2008 - what instance name did you pick? Did you install a default instance, or a named instance? And in the startup screen of SQL Server Management Studio: what happens if you **type in** either `.` for the local server (default instance) or `.\INSTANCE` for your named instance?